Smooth scroll, snappy scroll and anchor navigation at the same time
I was trying to achieve smooth and snappy scrolling while having anchor navigation at an HTML component. Only one "tab" should be visible at a time. The user would have to click in the tab name in order to change the current "tab".
The problem I am facing is that I can not have both features at the same time. If the scrolling is snappy, then the smooth animation is not carried out and vice versa.
I will also want to make that the user can drag the tab content in order to change the current tab, but this is for another question.
Code: (Uses tailwind, but it is not relevant)


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>
<html lang="en-GB">

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 bg-red-500">
      <a aria-label="Lorem ipsum" href="#lorem-ipsum">Lorem ipsum</a>
      <a aria-label="Amet porttitor" href="#amet-porttitor">Amet porttitor</a>
      <a aria-label="Blandit turpis" href="#blandit-turpis">Blandit turpis</a>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-row snap-x snap-mandatory overflow-x-auto overflow-y-auto max-h-[100vh]">
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="lorem-ipsum">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="amet-porttitor">
          Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="blandit-turpis">
          Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu. In eu s augue neque gravida. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. A
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <style is:global>
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
      html {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
      }
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>




I had a very similar problem once while dealing with two types of scrolling behaviour simultaneously.
I found an answer somwhere stating that "The issue might arise because both functions are trying to manipulate the scroll behavior of the page at the same time, potentially interfering with each other's scrolling animations.". Try awaiting the first scroll operation to complete before initiating the second one using js.

With a bit of JavaScript, it's possible:


document.querySelectorAll('main > div a').forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default anchor click behavior

    const targetId = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1); // Get the target ID
    const targetElement = document.getElementById(targetId);

    if (targetElement) {
      targetElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
        inline: 'nearest'
      });
    }
  });
});
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>
<html lang="en-GB">

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 bg-red-500">
      <a aria-label="Lorem ipsum" href="#lorem-ipsum">Lorem ipsum</a>
      <a aria-label="Amet porttitor" href="#amet-porttitor">Amet porttitor</a>
      <a aria-label="Blandit turpis" href="#blandit-turpis">Blandit turpis</a>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-row snap-x snap-mandatory overflow-x-auto overflow-y-auto max-h-[100vh]">
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="lorem-ipsum">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="amet-porttitor">
          Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi. Ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="min-w-[100vw] min-h-[80vh] snap-start">
        <p id="blandit-turpis">
          Blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu. In eu s augue neque gravida. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor. A
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <style is:global>
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }
    
    @media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
      html {
        scroll-behavior: auto;
      }
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>



